# how to change the value for an input type file by calling a function?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input id="inputype" type="file" accept="image/*" value="../Images/whatever.gif">
```

> also can i change the value by calling a function?

this function will be invoked onclick.

```
function click() {
   document.getElementById('inputype').value = "../Images/whatever.gif";  
}
```

how do i get this to work?

Comment: Simple, you can't... massive security risk otherwise

Answer (score 1):

There is no default value in such a form element (imagine the security implications...).

If empty, it usually shows a label like:"Select a file to upload...".

If you want to have a plaecholder at all costs, you can fake it (like placing a div above the imput, and changing the appereance to look like one). I do not raccomand this approch.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're suggesting something they didn't ask for and you don't even recommend?!

Comment: That is the third option, for a more complete answer.
I'm simply pointing out that making a fake loading imput is always possible, therfore is also possible to make a default (that does not work, so it can't load files).

Answer (score 0):

To check for empty value for an input with type file:

```
if (document.getElementById("inputype").files.length === 0) {
  console.log("You have not selected a file yet.");
}
```